# Docker Remote API JSON schema definition

Tags: c++, json, docker

I have a program which communicates with docker dameon remotely using REST api. It receives the information about images, containers, repositories in json format. I want to translate this REST API output from json format into C++ structures.

JSON format is always takes the form of key, value pair where key is string, but value could be string, number, array, etc.

I would like to know if there is standard schema definition for docker json objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's the [official remote API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/). However, since it contains "only" example requests and no authoritative schema definitions, it's probably not what you're looking for.

There does **not seem to be** an official [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) for the Docker remote API. However, the API responses are directly generated from corresponding **Go structs** which you can all find in a single file in the [source code repository](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/types/types.go).

For example, consider the definition of the `Container` response type:

```
// GET  "/containers/json"
type Port struct {
    IP          string
    PrivatePort int
    PublicPort  int
    Type        string
}

type Container struct {
    ID         string            `json:"Id"`
    Names      []string          `json:",omitempty"`
    Image      string            `json:",omitempty"`
    Command    string            `json:",omitempty"`
    Created    int               `json:",omitempty"`
    Ports      []Port            `json:",omitempty"`
    SizeRw     int               `json:",omitempty"`
    SizeRootFs int               `json:",omitempty"`
    Labels     map[string]string `json:",omitempty"`
    Status     string            `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

This basically contains all possible keys and their data types that you might encounter when requesting the `/containers/json` URI. All other resource representations can also be found the same way.

Comment: Cool, but still clunky, they should really provide a clean schema, also for the new Registry V2 API.
So now I only need a Go->JSON schema converter so I can generate my Java POJOs;=)